# GatsbyJS + Google Analytics = "No HTTP Response" Error?

Tags: http, google-analytics, response, gatsby

I've poured my time almost 4-5 hours to figure it out, but I couldn't have done with it... but fortunately, succeeded my Gatsby APP acknowledges the Google Analytics.
However, The problem occurs "No HTTP response Detected" from `Google Tag Assistant` Chrome Extension.
I've pasted the Google Analytics Snippets many times into `HTML.js`, `Index.html` and updated the latest version of GatsbyJs as well.

Additionally, I've tried to turn off my `Adblock` extension as well! but all failed...

**URL**
[The error occurred blog](https://ollagada.github.io)

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
// Note: it must *not* have a trailing slash.
siteMetadata: {
    title: 'SJ personal Blog',
    siteUrl: `https://ollagada.github.io`
},
plugins: [
    {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
        options: {
          trackingId: "MY TRACKING ID",
          // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
          head: true,
          // Setting this parameter is optional
          anonymize: true,
          // Setting this parameter is also optional
          respectDNT: true,
          // Avoids sending pageview hits from custom paths
          exclude: ["/preview/**", "/do-not-track/me/too/"],
          // Enables Google Optimize using your container Id
          optimizeId: "YOUR_GOOGLE_OPTIMIZE_TRACKING_ID",
          // Any additional create only fields (optional)
          sampleRate: 5,
          siteSpeedSampleRate: 10,
        },
      },

    {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-gtag`,
        options: {
          // your google analytics tracking id
          trackingId: `MY TRACKING ID`,
          // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
          head: true,
          // enable ip anonymization
          anonymize: true,
        },
      },

    'gatsby-transformer-remark', {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
        options: {
            name: `posts`,
            path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/posts`
         }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet', {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
        options: {
            name: 'gatsby-starter-default',
            short_name: 'starter',
            start_url: '/',
            background_color: '#663399',
            theme_color: '#663399',
            display: 'minimal-ui',
            icon: 'src/img/moi.jpg', // This path is relative to the root of the site.
        }
    }, 

]
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "description": "Gatsby default starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews ",
  "dependencies": {
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "gatsby": "^2.0.75",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-gtag": "^1.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.5",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.1.17",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.1",
    "instafeed.js": "^1.4.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-instafeed": "^0.4.0",
    "react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.13.2",
    "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
    "react-spinkit": "^3.0.0",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.9",
    "window": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write '**/*.js'",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -b master -d public"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  }
}
```

Thank you! Lovely Day!

Comment: When I look at the given Url this seems to work (as per the GA debugger). So this might still be a problem with your computer (unless of course you have solved your problem since you asked the question).

Comment: Actually, It's fixed up when I changed the IP address changes to 127.0.0.1:8000 from https://ollagada.github.io